# html5 video tag to display videos in same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I want to create a youtube like video slider for my web application using HTML5 and JS.In below code, when I click on image from slider it opens up youtube page and plays video. I want the youtube video to be played in same frame/div tag **rather than redirecting to youtube**.

My code is like this -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<link href="js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="themes/6/mcVideoPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript">
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="sliderFrame"> 
        <div id="slider">
            <a class="video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZDYsSOngik">
                <img src="image-slider-1.jpg" />
                <img src="video.jpg" />
            </a>
            <a class="video" href="video.mp4">
                <img src="image-slider-2.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 1"/> 
                <img src="video.jpg" />
            </a>            
            <a class="video" href="video.mp4">
                <img src="image-slider-3.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 2"/>
                <img src="video.jpg" />
            </a>
            <a class="video" href="video.mp4">
                <img src="image-slider-4.jpg"/>
                <img src="video.jpg" />
            </a>
            <a class="video" href="video.mp4">
                <img src="image-slider-5.jpg" />
                <img src="video.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please read the below article 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed width="420" height="345" src="youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"; type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> </embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **embedded version** of youtube links in your code.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/aZDYsSOngik" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can adjust the height and width of your video in the above code.
Also frameborder and allowfullscreen option.

> You can find your embedded video link under share>embed option under
>   the video in youtube.